# $L^p$ space and continuous injection

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

Let $1\leq p < r < q \leq \infty$ and $E\in \mathbb{R}$. Define 
$$A = L^p(E) + L^q(E) = \{f=g+h:g\in L^p(E), h\in L^q(E) \}$$

and $$\|f\|_A = \inf_{f=g+h} \|g\|_p+\|h\|_q$$ where the infimum is taken over all decompositions of $f$.

I already showed that $L^r(E) \subset A$ and that $\|f\|_A \leq \|f\|_r^{r/p} + \|f\|_r^{r/q}$, and now i must use this to prove that the injection of $L^r$ into $A$ is continuous to conclude that there exist $C>0$ such that
$$\|f\|_A \leq C\|f\|_r.$$ Any hint?

Comment: How is $r$ related to $p, q$? Perhaps $r \ge \max(p,q)$? Also, your estimate does not scale correctly.

Comment: $r \in (p,q)$ why you say that?

Comment: Apply the estimate that you already proved to $f/\|f\|_r$ instead of $f$ and see what happens.